# Oracle Date subtraction and define variable

Tags: oracle, date, variables

I am new to Oracle, but know TSQL
To test the functionality of date subtraction, I have written the following code:

```
define LaterDate = TO_DATE('05 Apr 2002');
define EarlierDate = &&LaterDate - 3;
SELECT TO_NUMBER(&&LaterDate - &&EarlierDate)  as DATEDIFF from dual;
```

This does not work as expected, whereas the following code does:

```
define LaterDate = TO_DATE('05 Apr 2002');
define EarlierDate = TO_DATE('02 Apr 2002');
SELECT TO_NUMBER(&&LaterDate - &&EarlierDate)  as DATEDIFF from dual;
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me? I suspect I am doing something "wrong" with the "variables" Perhaps there is something wrong with using double && vs single & but I am not sure? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "This does not work as expected" isn't entirely helpful; presumably the issue is that the first one gets -3 instead of +3? Rather than it erroring or doing something else odd?

Comment: With hindsight (what a wonderful thing!), I agree. I will take your comment on board, and try to formulate my question more clearly next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `set verify on` then you can see the problem; your first attempt gets:

```
define LaterDate = TO_DATE('05 Apr 2002');
define EarlierDate = &&LaterDate - 3;
SELECT TO_NUMBER(&&LaterDate - &&EarlierDate)  as DATEDIFF from dual;

old:SELECT TO_NUMBER(&&LaterDate - &&EarlierDate)  as DATEDIFF from dual
new:SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_DATE('05 Apr 2002') - TO_DATE('05 Apr 2002') - 3)  as DATEDIFF from dual

  DATEDIFF
----------
        -3
```

The operators are evaluated left to right, because they are all at the same level; so it first does

```
TO_DATE('05 Apr 2002') - TO_DATE('05 Apr 2002')
```

which is zero; then (effectively)

```
0 - 3
```

which is -3.

The `TO_NUMBER()` isn't needed as it's already a number, and you shouldn't be relying on NLS date settings for your date format. It's easier to use ANSI literals in this case anyway; but the important change is to add parentheses to the `EarlierDate` definition so its `- 3` is evaluated first:

```
define LaterDate = DATE '2002-04-05'
define EarlierDate = (&&LaterDate - 3)
SELECT &&LaterDate - &&EarlierDate as DATEDIFF from dual;

old:SELECT &&LaterDate - &&EarlierDate as DATEDIFF from dual
new:SELECT DATE '2002-04-05' - (DATE '2002-04-05' - 3) as DATEDIFF from dual

  DATEDIFF
----------
         3
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it is beginning to make sense to me now :-)

Answer (score -1):

You have to subtract a time period or interval from the date not just a number.

Try this:

```
define LaterDate = TO_DATE('05 Apr 2002');
define EarlierDate = &&LaterDate - INTERVAL '3' DAY;
SELECT TO_NUMBER(&&LaterDate - &&EarlierDate)  as DATEDIFF from dual;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I tried this, and came up with following error:

    ORA-30081: invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic
    30081. 00000 -  "invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic"
    *Cause:    The data types of the operands are not valid for datetime/interval arithmetic.
    *Action:
    Error at Line: 3 Column: 66

Comment: Oracle date arithmetic works with numbers - you don't need INTERVALs (although you can use them)

Comment: And this doesn't solve the actual problem; you still subtract the two dates first (which gets zero), then you try to subtract an interval from *that* (which gets the ORA-30081 error). Adding parentheses would fix this too, of course.